# "Why are you rejecting this edit?" pops up multiple times

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, user-interface, review

On a sufficently wide enough screen the *"Why are you rejecting this edit?"* popup can be triggered to open multiple times when the "Reject" button isn't fully covered by it.

I just noticed this when (*ducks*) *double-clicking* the "Reject" button then rejecting a suggested edit in the second pop-up. My vote was accepted and the second pop-up closed to reveal its predecessor (the first one).

Although not a major issue, I'd suggest temporarily disabling the buttons after the pop-up is displayed or showing the pop-up over a faded out layer (e.g. a 50% opacity `<div>`, making a second involuntary click [unpossible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iSD9lPVY6Q)).

Comment: http://www.memecenter.com/fun/98918/Double-Click

Comment: Argh. I should have predicted this. May I hint on that I actually *latently* clicked twice instead of *intentionally*?

Comment: I'm not fussed, just thought it was funny that you ducked!

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in latest, I disable the entire panel if you pop that window up.

Comment: to be deployed ...

Comment: Seems to have been deployed. Pressing `Esc` to close the layer doesn't seem to work anymore, however. Can you confirm this, or am I starting to make things up?

Comment: @LinusKleen yes that is broken (it works but does not enable the buttons) will fix